# WPF: prevent mouseleave event from firing with previewmousedown

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a customized animated button with this style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuBtnMouseEnterSb">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.92"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase Exponent="2" EasingMode="EaseInOut"></ExponentialEase>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.92"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <ExponentialEase Exponent="2" EasingMode="EaseInOut"></ExponentialEase>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuBtnMouseExitSb">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <BounceEase Bounces="1" Bounciness="5"></BounceEase>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <BounceEase Bounces="1" Bounciness="5" EasingMode="EaseInOut">
                                    </BounceEase>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuBtnMouseClickSb" AutoReverse="True">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.75"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2"></DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.75"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                        
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Transparent" CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" x:Name="btnScaleTransform"></ScaleTransform>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <Border.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MenuBtnMouseEnterSb}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MenuBtnMouseExitSb}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseDown">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MenuBtnMouseClickSb}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Border.Triggers>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Basically, whenever mouse enters this button - button becomes smaller and when `PreviewMouseDown` event happens (when I press mouse button) it must become even more small. But what actually happens is that button returns to it's original size when I press a left button - i.e. `MouseLeave` event is fired and when I release left mouse button `MouseEnter` is fired again.

I added handlers for PreviewMouseDown and MouseLeave events and after `PreviewMouseDown` is handled - `MouseLeave` is handled immediately which I suppose is causing the MouseExit animation to run instead of MouseClick.

I've tested it again with `Console.Writeline`s in each handler and it seems that MouseLeave handler is not called but animation still works as I described earlier.

I removed MouseLeave eventtrigger and now proper mousedown animation is running but it returns only to 0.92 scale (MouseEnter animation) and cannot return to original size when cursor is outside (that's what MouseLeave animation did).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is simple: Use `VisualState`s instead of `Trigger`s for such task.

I just copied my animations into `VisualState`s and they now work as I expected:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase Bounces="1" Bounciness="5"></BounceEase>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase Bounces="1" Bounciness="5" EasingMode="EaseInOut">
                                                </BounceEase>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.92"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase Exponent="2" EasingMode="EaseInOut"></ExponentialEase>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.92"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase Exponent="2" EasingMode="EaseInOut"></ExponentialEase>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.75"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="btnScaleTransform"
                                    To="0.75"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Although it is kind of weird how Trigger based animations work...